# Append output of sqlcmd to file using Job Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, export-to-csv, sqlcmd, sql-job

After some research I found the solution to append the output of a sqlcmd command to a csv file. Everything is fine when using the Command Shell:

```
C:\temp>sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -d <DATABASE> -E -Q "SELECT [something] FROM [TableX] WHERE [columnY] IS NOT NULL;" -W -h-1 -s";" >>"<FULL_PATH_TO_CSV-FILE>"
```

I want to schedule this stuff by using SQL Server Job Agent (with same account as with console) so I add a Job (type CmdExec). Job execution fails with the following error (unexpected argument):

> Meldung
>   Ausgeführt als Benutzer: ''[ACCOUNT]''. Sqlcmd: '>>''[FULL_PATH_TO_CSV-FILE]'': Unerwartetes Argument. Geben Sie '-?' ein, um die Hilfe anzuzeigen.  Prozessexitcode 1.  Fehler bei Schritt.

My workaround works fine: remove `>>"<FULL_PATH_TO_CSV-FILE>"` and use the output file of the step. But: I want to use the output file for logging purposes - not for the data output ...

The question is: why does the ">>" command does not work within a SQL Server Agent job?

I don't want to simply redirect the output. I know that sqlcmd provides the parameter `-o` for that. In this case an existing file would be overwritten. That's not what I want.

Unfortunatelly I do not have the reputation to post the screenshots so far.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Best regards,
D.C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here that SQL server agent creates process "sqlcmd" and sends this whole line to it as a parameters. So "sqlcmd" doesn't know what this means - ">>..." and returns with error.

To use this (">>") Command Shell syntax you should call it in the SQL agent. So try:

> cmd.exe /c "sqlcmd -S  -d  -E -Q "SELECT [something] FROM [TableX] WHERE [columnY] IS NOT NULL;" -W -h-1 -s";" >>"""

Comment: This solved it! Thank you very much! Unfortunately there is a new problem: no special chars (although I added -f 65001) :-(